How can I apply texture with simple tiling without stretching or scaling?
I have a simple texture, for example, a ceramic tile with a pixel size of 120x20. I want to apply it to a flat object in Blender with a size of 120x20 cm. This part works fine.
Now, I want to change the size of the object in Blender, for example, to a size of 120x40, and I want to see the tiled texture repeated so that there are 2 copies of the texture vertically. Another case is when I change the object size in Blender to 60x20, and I would like to have the texture cut in the middle. But in both cases, Blender stretches the texture.
In the answers that I found, it seems the recommended way to achieve this is by using scaling of the texture. But I wonder if there might be a simpler way to achieve this.
And an example with pictures. To demonstrate what I want to achieve, I will use a presentation program that allows tiling slides with images.
Example of texture.

Slide in original size, tiled with texture, and the texture keeps its aspect ratio and already tiled.

Slide size changed, but the texture maintains the same aspect ratio. The part of the texture that doesn’t fit into the width or height is just invisible.

But in Blender, I’m stuck with results like this: i.e., if I change the size of the object, the texture stretches.

I understand that this might not be the usual way to work with textures. But it still seems like my case is simple, and there should be an easy way to achieve it.
P.S. I’ve tried searching, but it seems like I’m using the wrong words, so I can’t find the answer.

New image for the comment 

Maybe this will work for you: In the Shader editor, Add a Geometry node. Connect the Position output to the input of the Image Texture node. In the Image texture node change the Projection type from the default Flat to Box.

If you're using blender 4.2 then you can just add a mesh plane that is fit to your image's aspect ratio automatically. Before 4.2 it's the same thing, just in a built-in addon. That's probably your best bet.

This has to do with something called a UV map. No, it’s not related to ultraviolet, rather, it maps a two dimensional coordinate system (U and V) to the three-dimensional mesh shape.
By default, a plane primitive UV map covers the 2-D UV space from 0 to 1 on both axes (whatever image texture you use always goes from 0 to 1 on both axes, but UV map points can go outside that). Thus, with the default map, no matter what shape or aspect ratio the plane is, the entire image will be stretched to cover exactly all of it. You want the image to cover less than all of it, so you need to stretch one side of the UV map beyond that 0 to 1 range. You can edit UV maps in the UV Editing screen.
Exactly what value the new edge position should be would be an inverse of how many times longer one edge of the plane is longer than the corresponding edge of the image (if the plane is already Object scaled to the right aspect ratio, this calculation is easier). Thankfully there’s a tool to do that math for you: Correct Face Attributes. In edit mode, turn that on, and you should be able to just stretch the face around as you please.

Sorry for the late response. I was experimenting with the described approach. Thank you, it works 95% of the time, and I will be able to do what I want. However, let me ask a couple more questions, as there may be room for improvement.
First, I want to say thank you to @Jakemoyo for the hint about importing images as meshes. If I create a plane first and then attach the texture to it, somehow the proportions are not right.

But if I first import the image as a mesh and then change the object's size, the proportions are predictable and easy to fix.
Now, some hiccups: vector transforming object->world works only on one plane, and if duplicated linked objects are not rotated. If I rotate the object, the texture gets stretched, and to fix it, I need to input the same rotation values into the mapping node. Is there a way to force objects to work like in the physical world?

I.e., if I rotate it, the texture will rotate with it. I've tried using different vector transforming combinations but haven't found a combination that forces the texture to work that way.
For example, the top object is the default object, and the object below is a duplicate with some rotation. You can see that the texture is skewed. (p.s. new image appended to the original question)

Please post that as a separate question. It’s related, but sounds like a problem in its own right and discussing it here would flood the comments. They don’t have a tree function like Reddit, you know.

Hi, may I ask you to check it https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/325703/how-can-i-keep-the-texture-on-an-object-unstretched-after-rotation
