How can I keep the texture on an object unstretched after rotation?
This is a follow-up question for this How can I apply texture with simple tiling without stretching or scaling? . The answer works in 95% of cases, but with the suggested vector transforming and mapping, the texture is being tiled along one surface/plane. If I rotate the object, the texture gets skewed. Example is shown in the screenshot. (The rotated plane is a duplicate of the top plane, both using the same texture configuration.)

I wonder if it is possible to force the texture to work like in the real world. For example, imagine you have a roll of wallpaper with a pattern. You can unroll it to get the necessary length for one strip/lane that will be glued to the wall. When you unroll it, the pattern is repeated. Now you have a strip of wallpaper prepared for one wall, but the next wall is rotated by 90 degrees. After rotating lane of wallpaper, the pattern on the lane remains the same.
For now, in Blender, if I want to keep the texture unchanged, I apply the same rotation value in the mapping node as duplicated object has.

Is there a reason to make the object bigger or smaller on last question? when you change an object size if the new size is equal to the same size, but smaller, you will get the same UV size, because you are just changing the 3D object. If you change the size to a different that the original size on a different dimension (Example: 120X20 to a 100X20) you are basically making a new shape from the original object and the UV are getting stretched and that's where the deformation occurs. An option is to make the image smaller or bigger to get a tile effect instead of changing the 3D object.

With the UV option correctly, it should work as in real world. Example :
https://imgur.com/a/GbdjsQl BUT i'm not sure what's your final goal

That isn’t the answer I gave to un-stretch the texture, and for this reason: Vector transformation will always have this problem.

If I understand what you're suggesting, the solution would be to fix/lock the UV map size, and then Blender will simply repeat it to fill the object with the texture if I will change object size.
I'm really new to Blender and I have to google everything I want to achieve. Could I ask you to provide more detailed steps for what you're suggesting?
As for the question about changing the size – yes, I want the object in Blender to behave like a real-world object. For example, if I cut a ceramic tile or wallpaper in the real world, the pattern or picture on them would stay the same.

You need to learn UV unwrap and textures. Basically, when you use the UV as a texture coordinate, your image is fixed to that object like in real world; and like in real world you can not make an image pattern that is on a paper, bigger (Unless you add another paper with the same pattern) in Blender but you could reduce your final size to make smaller parts of that pattern and cut them if you add the vertices for it. example : https://imgur.com/a/gtYCdpp

Because you are only making a plane, you need to first drop the VECTOR TRANSFORM. But that's only for a plane, for other shapes, you first need to learn a bit more about UVs and textures.

It seems you also have to learn the basics about working in Object Mode and working in Edit Mode. On your other question you wrote in the comments, you want them to behave like in the real world, i.e. when you rotate the object, the texture should rotate with it. But no matter which of the standard Texture Coordinate outputs you use, like General, UV or Object, in all cases the texture already rotates with the object - unless you rotate the mesh in Edit Mode. That's why it seems to me you have a lot of modeling and texturing basics to learn which is impossible with one question.

I might not understand all the theory, although I think I need a vector transform to make the texture behave like in the real world. I have a texture sized for real-world dimensions, for example, 249x100 cm. I am creating a plane/image mesh with that size and applying the texture to it. Now, if I want to cut the plane in half, I change its size and let the vector transform node handle the calculations to keep the texture's aspect ratio and size on the modified object, and will just "hide" that does not fit new size.

If I want to increase the object's size, the vector transform node, with the "repeat" setting on the texture node, will tile the object and maintain the texture's aspect ratio. Without using the vector transform node, if I change the object's size, I would need to manually calculate how much to scale the texture to keep its aspect ratio. In general, I have a mesh plane that keeps the real-world texture size projected onto the Blender object's size. I've also applied a -30-degree rotation to the object on the Z-axis. If I input -30 in the mapping node, the texture will correct its skew.

https://imgur.com/a/K5ez4wg I'm looking for a way to tell Blender to do this automatically. If this is called by a different word/term, please excuse me; I don’t know it. And if there is an easier method, please share it, I would really appreciate it.

As for UV unwrapping, I'm not sure how it applies in my case. I've watched a couple of videos about it. From what I understand, UV unwrapping is necessary for complex objects when I want to wrap them with textures and keep the aspect ratio. I am working with flat objects, such as ceramic tiles, where a standard flat projection works perfectly. All I need is to figure out how to make Blender repeat or tile the texture, maintain the aspect ratio, and prevent skewing when rotating the object.
